# How to set a button to run command in Xcode

Tags: xcode

So I'm making a very simple app in Xcode using Objective C. I've added a button to the UI but how to I add it so when it's pressed it runs a bash script? This is an app for macOS. I've got my GUI built just don't know how to make the buttons work. Thanks

Comment: Maybe have a look at tutorials first, this is basic Xcode stuff. There are also a lot of answers for something like that at stack overflow. I've just googled it and found plenty answers ;)

Comment: I can't find anything. It all seems to be for Swift. I just need the button to run a shell script on click.